# Why does it only show one command?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Why does it only show one slash command in the discord server? It only shows the first one and not the second one.

```
# Slash Command
@client.tree.command(name="joke")
async def joke(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(random.choice(jokes)) 

@client.tree.command(name="hello")
async def hello(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Hey {interaction.user.mention}", ephemeral=True)
```

I tried changing the order of the commands and it still only showed the first one.

Comment: Are you syncing the commands with Discord?

Comment: Yes. It always says 2 commands synced. Do I have to do it separately? @Hazzu

Comment: make sure to restart your discord after syncing. At least for me that helped when I had the same issues

Comment: restarting it worked. @sicco14